# Deceptive links in answers

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

Just a heads up really...

In the last couple of days I've noticed a couple of deceptive links in two answers by two different (unregistered) users. Whilst the answers themselves seem to be legitimate (and good), the reference link is spammy.

The links visibly show an "official" looking URL (eg. `moz.com` or `google.com`) but actually link to `wordpressgeekhelp.blogspot.co.uk`. This (new) website appears to simply copy articles from other websites in a blatant attempt at self promotion by plagiarism (even copying the Google support pages word for word).

The answers in question (already edited):

- [URL structures for SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84581/url-structures-for-seo/84583#84583)
- [Should I place rel='nofollow' in Google drive's file download link for good SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84541/should-i-place-rel-nofollow-in-google-drives-file-download-link-for-good-seo/84543#84543)

Continued...

- [How to change my id and name in php url](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84639/how-to-change-my-id-and-name-in-php-url/84643#84643)
- [Will I lose my MozRank / MozTrust / Page Authority if I upgrade my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84645/will-i-use-my-mozrank-moztrust-and-mozpageauthority-if-i-upgrade-my-site/84647#84647)
- [Using swear language - affects Google results and SEO in general negatively?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84627/using-swear-language-affects-google-results-and-seo-in-general-negatively/84644#84644)
- [Number of users changes when applying segments in google analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84641/number-of-users-changes-when-applying-segments-in-google-analytics/84642#84642)

**UPDATE:** I notice that the above blog (`wordpressgeekhelp.blogspot.co.uk`) is no longer available.

> Blog has been removed.

Comment: I saw a few of these. I edited the link to point to the reputable source and then flagged the post as spam. Sneaky little so and so!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up. Flag 'em when you see them, edit the post accordingly, and we'll take care of the (former) user.

Comment: Did you delete the user?  If so it looks like it caused the Community user to delete the posts.   That is a shame, because the answers were good other than the deceptive link.

Comment: I did. They plagiarized content, spammed us, and did it as an organized ring. But we can undelete the answers which I just did. :)